# Is it possible to pass slice to slice from golang to c++ through swig

Tags: c++, go, swig

I have known how to use swig to combine go and c++ together.
But now I have a go function
`func encode(demo [][]byte)`, in this function I want to pass demo to c++ function.
In c++, my function is like this `void encode(unsigned char** demo)`
So how can I do this, or is there any document tell me how to do this?